# Is there any better way to solve this regular expression in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I've Python list like below,

```
l = ['ac no **82....383 is as on 6767', 'ac **82....383 in for 23-23']
```

I've written Python regular expression to extract any number at position of '383' in above elements of list:

```
for i in l:
    match = re.search(r'ac.*\.([\d]*)\s(is|in)', i)
    if match: print match.group(1)
```

It works fine.
But it won't work for this.

```
l = ['ac no **82....383 of as on 2737183']
```

I can solve this by tweaking the same regular expression. But would really appreciate if a better way is available.

Comment: Because you have `of` after that number

Comment: Yeah i know that but i would like to solve it without depending on 'of', say by changing it from greedy to non-greedy. Something like that.

Comment: Are there always 4 dots before?

Comment: You can't say that there will be always three dots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
ac.*?\.([\d]*)\b
    ^         ^
```

- `?` to make it non greedy
- `\b` to make it independent of `is, of, in etc..`

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nX9vQ7/1)

i.e:

```
match = re.search(r'ac.*?\.([\d]*)\b', i)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of that you have the word `of` after your number while you didn't define such situation in your regex (you just defined `is` or `in`). you can also add `of` in group `(is|in)` or as a general way you can use another regex.

For example you can use `r'\.{3,}(\d*)` as your regex that match numbers that precede by 3 or more dot.

```
>>> l = ['ac no **82....383 is as on 6767', 'ac **82....38300 in for 23-23','ac no **82....323 of as on 2737183']
>>> for i in l:
...     match = re.search(r'ac.*\.{3,}(\d*)', i)
...     if match: print match.group(1)
... 
383
38300
323
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it without regex at all, for example:

```
a = 'ac no **82....383 of as on 2737183'

print a.split(".")[-1].split(" ")[0]

==> 383
```